# Lodash create new array from selected keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

My prop data is outputed as:

```
const { profile } = this.props;
console.log("help", profile);

{notes: "", name: "John", gender: "M", dob: "", age: "33", nationality: "British", notes2: "no notes", notes3: "no notes"}
```

I want to be able to pull out the notes and end up with something like this:

```
{notes: "", notes2: "no notes", notes3: "no notes"}
```

I need to keep "profile" as its own prop so would need to create a const to store this output.

I tried something like this:

```
const oldArray = _.map(_.toPairs(profile), d => _.fromPairs([d]));
const newArray = _.map(oldArray => [{notes: notes}, {notes: notes2}, {notes: notes3}]);
```

The reason I want to do this is to then run a check to see if all notes are empty, but cant do this whilst they sit in the array with lots of different keys.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to achieve...so you want to see if notes, notes2 and notes3 are empty for the object profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an object you could use `_.pick` method and return a new object with specific properties.

```js
const obj = {notes: "", name: "John", gender: "M", dob: "", age: "33", nationality: "British", notes2: "no notes", notes3: "no notes"}
const notes = _.pick(obj, ['notes', 'notes2', 'notes3']);
console.log(notes)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the keys of that object and check if the key has `notes` as a substring. If yes then add that `key-value` to a new object. Using this you do not need to worry about keys like `notes1`, `notes2`, `notes3`, ... and so on. You can simply check for the substring `notes`:

```js
var obj = {notes: "", name: "John", gender: "M", dob: "", age: "33", nationality: "British", Notes2: "no notes", notes3: "no notes"};
var res = {};
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  if(key.toLowerCase().indexOf('notes') !== -1){
    res[key] = obj[key];
  }
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain js instead of lodash:

```
const { profile } = this.props;
const { notes, notes2, notes3 } = profile;
const newObject  = { notes, notes2, notes3 };
```

Then you can check the values:

```
const hasValues = Object.values(newObject).filter(v => !!v).length > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`_.pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pickBy) with [`String.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) (or [lodash's equivalent](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#startsWith)) to find all the keys that start with the word **notes**:

```js
const props = {notes: "", name: "John", gender: "M", dob: "", age: "33", nationality: "British", notes2: "no notes", notes3: "no notes"};

const notes = _.pickBy(props, (v, k) => k.startsWith('notes'));

console.log(notes)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```